# Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: File should not depend on itself. on asp.net core 3.1 visual studio windows

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, virtualbox

Tried to open a project created in visual studio for mac in Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows VM and received this error.

```
=====================
8/22/2020 3:14:58 AM
NotRecoverable
Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: File should not depend on itself.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.ResolveDependentItems(Dictionary`2 pendingItemsByDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.GenerateOriginalTree(ConfiguredProjectExports configuredProjectExports, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.PhysicalProjectTreeProvider.<GenerateOriginalTreeAsync>d__208.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectTreeProviderBase.TreeUpdateSubmission.<UpdateTree>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CoreProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass76_1.<<Initialize>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CoreProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass78_0.<<SubmitTreeUpdateCoreAsync>g__waitOnTask|0>d.MoveNext()
RunningInVisualStudio Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.RetailRuntime HostSetActiveProjectConfiguration
===================
```

Comment: Please check if it is a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/Known+Issue+in%3A+Visual+Studio+2019+Version+16.0.html). If not, you can [report a problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8)

Comment: Not very much info for this issue, but 2 useful links: https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/1239
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/79085/error-loading-project-file-should-not-depend-on-it.html

Comment: @RoarS. your first link was the solution. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue in a proj file setting dependencies for Generated and other dependent files.
In my case dependent file mask File*.cs includes File.cs

`<ItemGroup Label="Database"> <Compile Update="Data\File*.cs"> <DependentUpon>File.cs</DependentUpon>`